# Can't categorize data using R

Tags: r, model

I tried to categorize my data so I could make a logistic regression model. I'm quite new to R and learning it for my study. I have used this code that I have seen in multiple examples, yet nothing goes through and stays the same. No errors are given either.

```
ds <- read.csv("adult.csv")
colnames(ds)<- c("age","workclass","responsenum","education","education_years","marital_status","occupation","familyrole", "race","sex", "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hours_per_week","country", "income") 

ds$workclass <- as.character(ds$workclass)
ds$workclass[ds$workclass == "Without-pay" | ds$workclass == "Never-worked"] <- "Jobless"
ds$workclass[ds$workclass == "State-gov" | ds$workclass == "Local-gov"]  <- "govt" 
ds$workclass[ds$workclass == "Self-emp-inc" | ds$workclass == "Self-emp-not-inc"]  <- "Self-employed"
```

When I use table() after, I still get the old names out of it.

Anyone knows what is going wrong?

The output of dput(head(ds)) =

```
structure(list(age = c(50L, 38L, 53L, 28L, 37L, 49L), workclass = c(" Self-emp-not-inc", 
" Private", " Private", " Private", " Private", " Private"), 
    responsenum = c(83311L, 215646L, 234721L, 338409L, 284582L, 
    160187L), education = c(" Bachelors", " HS-grad", " 11th", 
    " Bachelors", " Masters", " 9th"), education_years = c(13L, 
    9L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 5L), marital_status = c(" Married-civ-spouse", 
    " Divorced", " Married-civ-spouse", " Married-civ-spouse", 
    " Married-civ-spouse", " Married-spouse-absent"), occupation = c(" Exec-managerial", 
    " Handlers-cleaners", " Handlers-cleaners", " Prof-specialty", 
    " Exec-managerial", " Other-service"), familyrole = c(" Husband", 
    " Not-in-family", " Husband", " Wife", " Wife", " Not-in-family"
    ), race = c(" White", " White", " Black", " Black", " White", 
    " Black"), sex = c(" Male", " Male", " Male", " Female", 
    " Female", " Female"), capital_gain = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), capital_loss = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hours_per_week = c(13L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 16L), country = c(" United-States", " United-States", 
    " United-States", " Cuba", " United-States", " Jamaica"), 
    income = c(" <=50K", " <=50K", " <=50K", " <=50K", " <=50K", 
    " <=50K")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from `dput(head(ds))`? If the first few rows of the frame are not very useful, then perhaps `dput(ds[c(1,3,5,7),1:3])` (where the first vec is interesting-rows, and the `1:3` is if we only need a few columns).

Comment: I agree with @r2evans. I tested your code on a mocked data frame and it worked just fine. We need a glimpse of your data to understand what is going on and to replicate on our systems. Please add it to your question.

Comment: structure(list(X39 = c(50L, 53L, 37L, 52L), State.gov = c(" Self-emp-not-inc", 
" Private", " Private", " Self-emp-not-inc"), X77516 = c(83311L, 
234721L, 284582L, 209642L)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L), class = "data.frame") is the output when i used dput(ds[c(1,3,5,7),1:3])

Comment: I don't see `workclass` in that data, but ... all of the strings there have leading spaces. You can fix it globally with something like `ischr <- sapply(ds, is.character); ds[ischr] <- lapply(ds[ischr], trimws)`, and then try again.

Comment: I have created workclass as my own header using colnames()

Comment: ischr <- sapply(ds, is.character); ds[ischr] <- lapply(ds[ischr], trimws) worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has leading spaces, so `" Self-imp-not-inc"` will never match `"Self-emp-not-inc"`.

Thoughts:

- You can trim leading/trailing whitespace from all string-like columns.

  ```r
  str(ds, list.len = 4)
  # 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  15 variables:
  #  $ X39          : int  50 38 53 28 37 49
  #  $ State.gov    : chr  " Self-emp-not-inc" " Private" " Private" " Private" ...
  #  $ X77516       : int  83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187
  #  $ Bachelors    : chr  " Bachelors" " HS-grad" " 11th" " Bachelors" ...
  #   [list output truncated]
  ischr <- sapply(ds, is.character)
  ischr
  #           X39     State.gov        X77516     Bachelors           X13 Never.married  Adm.clerical Not.in.family 
  #         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE 
  #         White          Male         X2174            X0           X40 United.States        X..50K 
  #          TRUE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE          TRUE 
  ds[ischr] <- lapply(ds[ischr], trimws)
  str(ds, list.len = 4)
  # 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  15 variables:
  #  $ X39          : int  50 38 53 28 37 49
  #  $ State.gov    : chr  "Self-emp-not-inc" "Private" "Private" "Private" ...
  #  $ X77516       : int  83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187
  #  $ Bachelors    : chr  "Bachelors" "HS-grad" "11th" "Bachelors" ...
  #   [list output truncated]
  ```
- Or, you can add spaces to all of your patterns, now something like:

  ```r
  ds$workclass[ds$workclass == " Without-pay" | ds$workclass == " Never-worked"] <- " Jobless"
  ds$workclass[ds$workclass == " State-gov" | ds$workclass == " Local-gov"]  <- " govt" 
  ds$workclass[ds$workclass == " Self-emp-inc" | ds$workclass == " Self-emp-not-inc"]  <- " Self-employed"
  ```

  (I don't think this is the best way to go, so I'll assume that you chose to use `trimws` as in the first bullet.)
- You might simplify some of your `|`'s with `%in%`:

  ```r
      ds$workclass[ds$workclass %in% c("Without-pay", "Never-worked")] <- "Jobless"
      ds$workclass[ds$workclass %in% c("State-gov", "Local-gov")]  <- "govt" 
      ds$workclass[ds$workclass %in% c("Self-emp-inc", "Self-emp-not-inc")]  <- "Self-employed"
  ```
- You can also create a dictionary of sorts that translates from some to others. For instance,

  ```r
  translations <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = "
  src,tgt
  Without-pay,Jobless
  Never-worked,Jobless
  State-gov,govt
  Local-gov,govt
  Self-emp-inc,Self-employed
  Self-emp-not-inc,Self-employed")

  ds$State.gov
  # [1] "Self-emp-not-inc" "Private"          "Private"          "Private"          "Private"          "Private"         
  ifelse(ds$State.gov %in% translations$src, translations$tgt[ match(ds$State.gov, translations$src) ], ds$State.gov)
  # [1] "Self-employed" "Private"       "Private"       "Private"       "Private"       "Private"      
  ds$State.gov <- ifelse(ds$State.gov %in% translations$src,
                         translations$tgt[ match(ds$State.gov, translations$src) ],
                         ds$State.gov)
  ```

  (This technique might also be implemented as a `merge` or `dplyr::*_join` operation, but for now I think that may be more complicated than you need.)

  The main advantage (in my opinion) of using this dictionary-like translation is that it is the most easiest to see, understand, and maintain.